# Read a file from a folder with gson

Tags: java, gson

I want to get a file called `FIB.json` that is in the folder `(user.dir)/src/Saves/Facultat/FIB.json`.

I tried with `bufferedReader` and I'm getting null aswell.
I'm doing something so wrong, some hint?

```
public class PersistenceCtrl {
    private static final String SAVEFOLDER = System.getProperty("user.dir") 
    + "/src/Saves/";
    private static final String FACULTATFOLDER = SAVEFOLDER + "Facultat/";


public static String loadFacultat(String archivo)  {

    Gson gson = new Gson();
    try (FileInputStream fin = new FileInputStream(FACULTATFOLDER + 
        archivo)){
     try (ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(fin)){
            String p = (String) ois.readObject();
            System.out.println("try?");
            System.out.println(p);
            Facultat facultat = gson.fromJson(p,Facultat.class);
            return gson.toJson(facultat);
     } catch (Exception ex){}

    } catch(Exception e) {}
    System.out.println("Rip");
    return null;
}
```

> The code with bufferedReader was this:

```
public static String loadFacultat(String archivo)  {
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    BufferedReader bf = null;
    try{
        bf = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(FACULTATFOLDER + archivo));

    Facultat facultat = gson.fromJson(bf,Facultat.class);
    return gson.toJson(facultat);

    } catch(Exception e){
        System.out.println(e.toString());
    }


return null;

 }
```

It's getting my always to return null.

Comment: What does `new File(FACULTATFOLDER + archivo).exists()` say?

Comment: Add some output or print stacktraces into those emtpy catch blocks.

Comment: The exists() say's false :(

Comment: I found the mistake thanks guys ^^ (was the path)